# mysql optimization - copy or serialized old rows

Tags: mysql, database-optimization

Suppose i have a simple table with this columns:

|    id      |    user_id    |   order_id |

About 1,000,000 rows is inserted to this table per month and as it is clear relation between user_id and order_id is 1 to M.

The records in the last month needed for accounting issues and the others  is just for showing order histories to the users.To archive records before last past month,i have two options in my mind:
first,create a similar table and each month copy old records to it.so it will  get bigger and bigger each month according to growth of orders.
second,create a table like below:

|    id      |    user_id    |   order_idssss |

and each month, for each row to be inserted to this table,if there exist user_id,just update order_ids and add new order_id to the end of order_ids.
in this solution number of rows in the table will be get bigger according to user growth ratio.

suppose for each solution we have an index on user_id.
.
Now question is which one is more optimized for SELECT all order_ids per user in case of load on server.
the first one has much more records than the second one,but in the second one some programming language is needed to split order_ids.

Comment: Storing CSV data for the various order IDs sounds like an all around bad idea.  If you have an index setup on the first table, possibly on the timestamp, querying should not be so bad.  I vote for the first option.

Comment: Agreed with @Tim. Never ever store multiple values in one row. It's the very first normalization principle.

Answer (score 0):

**The first choice is the better choice** from among the two you have shown. With respect, I should say your second choice is a **terrible idea**.

MySQL (with all SQL dbms systems) is excellent at handling very large numbers of rows of uniformly laid out (that is, normalized) data.

But, your best choice is to do nothing except create appropriate indexes to make it easy to look up order history by date or by user.  Leave all your data in this table and optimize lookup instead.

Until this table contains at least fifty million rows (at least four years' worth of data), the time you spend reprogramming your system to allow it to be split into a current and an archive version will be far more costly than just keeping it together.

If you want help figuring out which indexes you need, you should ask another question showing your queries. It's not clear from this question how you look up orders by date.

Answer (score 0):

In a 1:many relationship, don't make an extra table.  Instead have the `user_id` be a column in the `Orders` table.  Furthermore, this is likely to help performance:

```
PRIMARY KEY(user_id, order_id),
INDEX(order_id)
```

Is a "month" a calendar month?  Or "30 days ago until now"?

If it is a calendar month, consider `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(datetime))` and have an ever-increasing list of monthly partitions.  However, do not create future months in advance; create them just before they are needed.  More details: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint

Note: This would require adding `datetime` to the end of the PK.

At 4 years' worth of data (48 partitions), it will be time to rethink things.  (I recommend not going much beyond that number of partitions.)

Read about "transportable tablespaces".  This may become part of your "archiving" process.

Use InnoDB.

With that partitioning, either of these becomes reasonably efficient:

```
WHERE user_id = 123
  AND datetime > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY

WHERE user_id = 123
  AND datetime >= '2017-11-01'  -- or whichever start-of-month you need
```

Each of the above will hit at most one non-empty partition more than the number of months desired.

If you want to discuss this more, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` (in any variation), plus some of the important `SELECTs`.